# SQL QUERY : Find for each year copies sold > 10000

Tags: sql

I am practicing a bit with `SQL` and I came across this exercise:

Consider the following database relating to albums, singers and sales:

Album (**Code**, Singer, Title)
Sales (**Album**, **Year**, CopiesSold)
with a constraint of referential integrity between the Sales Album attribute and the key of the
Album report. 
Formulate the following query in **SQL** :

- Find the code and title of the albums that have sold 10,000 copies
  every year since they came out.

I had thought of solving it like this:

```
SELECT CODE, TITLE, COUNT (*)
FROM ALBUM JOIN SALES ON ALBUM.Code = SALES.Album
WHERE CopiesSold > 10000
HAVING COUNT(*) = /* Select difference from current year and came out year.*/
```

Can you help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Is the year an album was released by the minimum `year` of it in the `sales` tables? And does `sales` cover all years from the release until now or can there be gaps?

Comment: Im sorry i don't understand the  question.

Comment: How would you look up in which year an album was released? And can there be years (from its release year to the current year) where there is no row in the `sales` table for an album?

Comment: For the first question from the first year the album appears.

For the second question yes, there may be years where there are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with an `INNER JOIN`, `GROUP BY`, and `HAVING`.

```
SELECT A.Code, A.Title
FROM ALBUM A
INNER JOIN SALES S ON S.Album = A.Code
GROUP BY A.Code, A.Title
HAVING MIN(S.CopiesSold) >= 10000
```

The `HAVING` clause will filter out albums whose minimum Copies Sold are < 10000.

**EDIT**

There was also a question about gaps in the `Sales` data, there are a number of ways to modify the above query to solve for this as well. One solution would be to use an embedded query to identify the correct number of years.

```
SELECT A.Code, A.Title
FROM ALBUM A
INNER JOIN SALES S ON S.Album = A.Code
GROUP BY A.Code, A.Title
HAVING MIN(S.CopiesSold) >= 10000 AND
       COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Year) FROM SALES WHERE Year >= MIN(s.Year))
```

This solution assumes that at least one album by some artist was sold each year (a fairly safe bet). If you had a `Years` table there are simpler solutions. If the data is current there are also solutions that utilize `DATEDIFF`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use correlated subqueries with `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` respectively.

1. In one check if the maximum year minus the minimum year plus one is equal to the count of records with a defined year of an album. That way you make sure you don't get albums where there are figures missing for a year and you therefore cannot tell whether they sold 10000 or more or not. Also check that the maximum year is the current year not to miss gaps between the maximum year and the current year. (In the example code I will use the literal `2020` but there are means to get that dynamically. They depend on the DBMS however and you didn't state which one you're using.)
2. In the second one check that there's no record with undefined sales figures or sales figures lower than 10000 for the album. If no such record exists, all of the existing one have to have figures of 10000 or greater.

```
SELECT a1.code,
       a1.title
       FROM album a1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ''
                            FROM sales s1
                            WHERE s1.album = a1.code
                            HAVING max(s1.year) - min(s1.year) + 1 = count(s1.year)
                                   AND max(s1.year) = 2020)
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM sales s2
                                    WHERE s2.album = a1.code
                                          AND s2.copiessold IS NULL
                                               OR s2.copiessold < 10000);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but I can't follow all the reasoning since I'm still practicing I prefer the answer above.

Comment: The other answer is great and way ahead of mine if there cannot be gaps. But since you said there can be gaps the other answer can give you wrong results. That's why I explicitly asked for the possibility of gaps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `ALL` keyword should work nicely here. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Album
WHERE 10000 <= ALL (
    SELECT CopiesSold FROM Sales
    WHERE Sales.Album = Album.Code)
```